# Store custom data against XboxLIVE Gamer in XNA?

Tags: xna-4.0, xbox-live

If I am using Xbox LIVE [Gamer Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb975583.aspx) for a networked XNA game, is there anyway to store custom data against the `Gamer` or `GamerProfile` so should they sign-in again even on a different machine I can access it? For example if I want to store their colour choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible, but it depends on user choice in order to function.

The method you mentioned, using Gamer Services, will not accomplish what you described.  That corner of the framework only serves up player default settings, not game-specific settings.  I believe color choices are included in that information.  But again, this is not their choice for *your* game, it is their default choice for all games.  (Gamer services does allow setting [temporary status info](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd231874.aspx).)

You will need to store custom data in the same manner that you would generate a save file, with [User Storage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb203921.aspx).  The process flow described in that article notes that you must call [`StorageDevice.BeginShowSelector`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.storage.storagedevice.beginshowselector.aspx), which displays the HDD/Memorystick/Cloud choices.  This is why your solution depends on player choice.

*IF* the player selects cloud storage on the first machine, and *if* they also select it on subsequent different machines, then they have access to the same saves in both locations.  If they choose local physical storage, that information is stuck on the single machine.